# Understanding an example about resumable functions in proposal N3650 for C++1y

Tags: c++, c++14

Consider the following example taken from [N3650](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3650.pdf):

```
int cnt = 0;
do {
   cnt = await streamR.read(512, buf);
   if (cnt == 0)
      break;
   cnt = await streamW.write(cnt, buf);
} while (cnt > 0);
```

I am probably missing something, but if I understood `async` and `await` well, what is the point in showing the usefulness of the two constructs with the above example when the  effects are equivalent to writing:

```
int cnt = 0;
do {
   cnt = streamR.read(512, buf).get();
   if (cnt == 0)
      break;
   cnt = streamW.write(cnt, buf).get();
} while (cnt > 0);
```

where both the `read().get()` and `write().get()` calls are synchronous?

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you'd form a complete example including the declaration and call of the resumable function.

Comment: Here is an example using Visual C++ November CTP implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309508/using-sqlite-winrt-from-a-c-windows-store-app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The await keyword is not equal to calling get on a future. You might look at it more like this, suppose you start from this:

```
future<T> complex_function()
{
     do_some_stuff();
     future<Result> x = await some_async_operation();
     return do_some_other_stuff(x);
}
```

This is functionally more or less the same as

```
future<T> complex_function()
{
     do_some_stuff();
     return some_async_operation().then([=](future<Result> x) {
         return do_some_other_stuff(x);
     });
}
```

Note the more or less, because there are some resource management implications, variables created in `do_some_stuff` shouldn't be copied to execute `do_some_other_stuff` like the lambda version will do.

The second variant makes it more clear what will happen upon invocation.

1. The `do_some_stuff()` will be invoked synchronously when you call `complex_function`.
2. `some_async_operation` is called asynchronously and results in a future. The exact moment when this operation is executed depends on your actual asynchronous calling implementation, it might be immediate when you use threads, it might be whenever the `.get()` is called when you use defered execution.
3. We don't execute `do_some_other_stuff` immediately, but rather chain it to the future obtained in step 2. This means that it can be executed as soon as the result from `some_async_operation` is ready but not before. Aside from that, it's moment of execution is determined by the runtime. If the implementation would just wrap the `then` proposal, this means it would inherit the parent future's executor/launch policy (as per N3558).
4. The function returns the last future, that represents the eventual result. Note this NEEDS to be a future, as part of the function body is executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 6):

A more complete example (hopefully correct):

```
future<void> forwardMsgs(istream& streamR, ostream& streamW) async
{
    char buf[512];
    int cnt = 0;
    do {
       cnt = await streamR.read(512, buf);
       if (cnt == 0)
          break;
       cnt = await streamW.write(cnt, buf);
    } while (cnt > 0);
}

future<void> fut = forwardMsgs(myStreamR, myStreamW);

/* do something */

fut.get();
```

The important point is (quoting from the draft):

> After suspending, a resumable function may be resumed by the scheduling logic of the runtime and will eventually complete its logic, at which point it executes a return statement (explicit or implicit) and sets the function’s result value in the placeholder.

and:

> A resumable function may continue execution on another thread after resuming following a suspension of its execution.

That is, the thread who originally called `forwardMsgs` *can* return at any of the suspension points. If it does, during the `/* do something */` line, the code inside `forwardMsgs` *can* be executed by another thread *even though* the function has been called "synchronously".

---

This example is very similar to

```
future<void> fut = std::async(forwardMsgs, myStreamR, myStreamW);

/* do something */

fut.get();
```

The difference is the resumable function can be executed by different threads: a different thread can resume execution (of the resumable function) after each resumption/suspension point.

Comment: *A resumable function may continue execution on another thread after resuming following a suspension of its execution.* This looks suspiciously like something from Haskell/Go/Rust: the language runtime makes asynchronous IO look synchronous from the user point of view and multiplexes execution streams on its own.

Comment: @MatthieuM. except that it is not (necessarily) the language runtime. You can use it with any form of asynchronous scheduling system that's built on top of futures and promises.

Comment: @KillianDS: well, it does involve the *scheduling logic of the runtime*, is there a way to customize this or is this provided by the implementation ? I did not wanted to suggest it was limited to IO, just that it seemed to me this was green-threads for C++ much as they exist in Haskell/Go/Rust (and probably other languages).

Comment: @MatthieuM. if I understand it correctly `await` would work with any call that returns a future itself. Be that `std::async`, some  defered reactor, a threadpool or greenthreads. I'm not under the impression that this by itself is linked to greenthreads.

Comment: @KillianDS: The fact that execution can start on one thread and be moved by the language runtime to another is quite the definition of green threads; since you no longer control the OS thread on which your code is executed.

Comment: @MatthieuM. then I use another definition of greenthreads (virtualized/simulated user-space threads iso actual OS threads). But you still have control. You actually say yourself 'execute the remainder of this function in the context of this asynchronous call'. It's not the runtime that decides but you.

Comment: @KillianDS: It is not clear to me that you actually have control here: *A resumable function may continue execution on another thread after resuming following a suspension of its execution.* seems to imply that when the async operation completes (possibly a system call), then execution may resume on a thread you did not choose explicitly.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Sorry, you're right, I missed that the implementation part based on `then` is apparently just an example, not a reference. If it doesn't need necessarily to wrap `then` a runtime-specific scheduling is indeed a possibility. A shame though, it would make more sense imho to give it the same or similar constraints as `then`, I don't like a runtime doing things like that for me (or at least not giving me the option to override it).

Answer (score 3):

I think the idea is that the `streamR.read()` and `streamW.write()` calls are asynchronous I/O operations and return futures, which are automatically waited on by the `await` expressions.

So the equivalent synchronous version would have to call `future::get()` to obtain the results e.g.

```
int cnt = 0;
do {
   cnt = streamR.read(512, buf).get();
   if (cnt == 0)
      break;
   cnt = streamW.write(cnt, buf).get();
} while (cnt > 0);
```

You're correct to point out that there is no concurrency here.  However in the context of a resumable function the `await` makes the behaviour different to the snippet above. When the `await` is reached the function will return a `future`, so the caller of the function can proceed without blocking even if the resumable function is blocked at an `await` while waiting for some other result (e.g. in this case the `read()` or `write()` calls to finish.)  The resumable function might resume running asynchronously, so the result becomes available in the background while the caller is doing something else.

Comment: "which are automatically waited on by the await expressions." This confused me a bit. Do you mean *automatically* as in *if/when it is required* (e.g. by calling `.get()` on the returned `future` of the resumable function)?

Comment: I made the question more clear by appending the get() after the calls. thanks.

Comment: @DyP, I believe the resumable function might resume execution spontaneously (in another thread) not only when `.get()` is called on the returned future. What I meant is that execution of the resumable function cannot proceed past the `await` operator until it has waited for its operand. I've edited my answer so I hope it's clearer

Answer (score 2):

Here's the correct translation of the example function to not use await:

```
struct Copy$StackFrame {
  promise<void> $result;
  input_stream& streamR;
  output_stream& streamW;
  int cnt;
  char buf[512];
};
using Copy$StackPtr = std::shared_ptr<Copy$StackFrame>;

future<void> Copy(input_stream& streamR, output_stream& streamW) {
  Copy$StackPtr $stack{ new Copy$StackFrame{ {}, streamR, streamW, 0 } };
  future<int> f$1 = $stack->streamR.read(512, stack->buf);
  f$1.then([$stack](future<int> f) { Copy$Cont1($stack, std::move(f)); });
  return $stack->$result.get_future();
}

void Copy$Cont1(Copy$StackPtr $stack, future<int> f$1) {
  try {
    $stack->cnt = f$1.get();
    if ($stack->cnt == 0) {
      // break;
      $stack->$result.set_value();
      return;
    }
    future<int> f$2 = $stack->streamW.write($stack->cnt, $stack->buf);
    f$2.then([$stack](future<int> f) { Copy$Cont2($stack, std::move(f)); });
  } catch (...) {
    $stack->$result.set_exception(std::current_exception());
  }
}

void Copy$Cont2(Copy$StackPtr $stack, future<int> f$2) {
  try {
    $stack->cnt = f$2.get();
    // while (cnt > 0)
    if (cnt <= 0) {
      $stack->$result.set_value();
      return;
    }
    future<int> f$1 = $stack->streamR.read(512, stack->buf);
    f$1.then([$stack](future<int> f) { Copy$Cont1($stack, std::move(f)); });
  } catch (...) {
    $stack->$result.set_exception(std::current_exception());
  }
}
```

As you can see, the compiler transformation here is quite complex. The key point here is that, unlike the `get()` version, the original `Copy` returns its future as soon as the first async call has been made.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with the meaning of the difference between these two code samples. Let's re write them a little to be more complete.

```
    // Having two functions
    future<void> f (istream&streamR, ostream&streamW) async
    {  int cnt = 0;
       do {
          cnt = await streamR.read(512, buf);
          if (cnt == 0)
             break;
          cnt = await streamW.write(cnt, buf);
       } while (cnt > 0);
    }
    void g(istream&streamR, ostream&streamW)
    {  int cnt = 0;
       do {
          cnt = streamR.read(512, buf).get();
          if (cnt == 0)
             break;
          cnt = streamW.write(cnt, buf).get();
       } while (cnt > 0);
    }
    // what is the difference between
    auto a = f(streamR, streamW);
    // and 
    auto b = async(g, streamR, streamW);
```

You still need at least three stacks. In both cases main thread is not blocked. Is it assumption that await would be implemented by compiler more efficiently than future<>:get()?. Well, the one without await can be used now.

Thanks
Adam Zielinski